# Does anyone have a backup strategy for SQL Azure databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I'm using SQL Azure on a project and it works great.  The problem is that the usual backup features do not exist.  I have exported the database a couple of times using SQLAzureMW ( http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/ ) but this tool is now choking trying to download the database data with bcp.  In any case, it's not as nice a solution as SQL Server backups.

Is anyone aware of a commercial or open source tool, or other technique, for making reliable backups of SQL Azure databases?  This is really a showstopper.

Comment: They announced SQL Azure data sync at PDC09 that allowed onsite SQL server to be kept in sync with SQL Azure, but I've not used it to test the overheads.

Comment: I downloaded this and am reading about it, thanks.  However, it seems more geared at pushing data from the local database to the Azure database.  Maybe I am misunderstanding it, but they seem to want you to start with a clean Azure database that will be populated by your on-site database.

Comment: We are using Redgate's SQL Azure Backup tool and are very happy so far. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10144308/135441

Answer (score 3):

Starting with update 4, SQL Azure now supports database copies.  You can make a copy of your database, kept in Azure, and use that to retrieve data in the event of an accidental deletion or schema bugaboo:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff951624.aspx

It's still up to you to get that database off Azure and onto your own local SQL Server, though, but at least you've got a mechanism for making a point-in-time copy.

Comment: Thanks, Brent.  This is indeed what we've used lately before a schema change.  It is a great feature for other purposes tool.  One step closer.  If we just had the ability to rip off a backup file and download it, we'd be there.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft takes care of the backups for you.  There is no reason to back up SQL Azure databases yourself.

Comment: Whilst MS take care of the backups, there are still a lot of good reasons to want your own copy. Check the limit of liability terms of the contract.

Comment: I certainly hope this is true, but I think we will need to periodically back up on our own.  MS does not give me any way to manage the backups they are supposedly creating.

Comment: I was just outlining how Microsoft has it working right now.  I never said I liked it or would trust it with my customer's production data.  That's why I host application on Amazon EC2 or Rackspace with a licensed copy of SQL Server that I control and backup.

Comment: Tom - "no reason" - seriously? So if you accidentally delete a row, that isn't a reason?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we had the same problem and couldn't find any good/simple solutions, so we cobbled together a solution using Red Gate: http://mooneyblog.mmdbsolutions.com/index.php/2011/01/11/simple-database-backups-with-sql-azure

Comment: I will check out their products, thanks.  We finally were able to get something working with bcp and am anxiously awaiting backup support in azure.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure will support PIT (Point in time) backup/restore (mainly restore) later this year (2011), CTP in summer. There is some (little) preliminary info here [info here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/DBI313).