# SQL Azure Backup & Restore strategy

Tags: sql, azure

We have a web based (ASP.NET MVC) application that uses SQL Server 2008 for its database.

Because the data is important to us (and our clients), we have a Backup & Restore strategy in place which, in a nutshell, looks like this:

```
-Weekly: Full database backup
-Nightly: Differential backup
-Hourly: Log backup
```

The strategy we use was greatly influenced by listening to a webcast done by Kimberly Tripp (which can be viewed here: https://msevents.microsoft.com/CUI/EventDetail.aspx?culture=en-US&EventId=1032278589&CountryCode=US).

**Question:**

Since we are looking into moving the database to SQL Azure, I wanted to know if anyone has put in place a similar Backup & Restore strategy within SQL Azure.

Has anyone encountered any known issues with trying to put in place a Backup & Restore strategy with Azure?

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Backup/restore is a whole different animal in SQL Azure as the traditional backup/restore commands are not available. See the article [SQL Azure Backup and Restore Strategy](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-backup-and-restore-strategy.aspx) for a good overview and then read [Copying Databases in SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951624.aspx). Also take a look at redgate's (beta) third party [tool for SQL Azure Backup](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-azure-backup/).

**EDIT**: Adding a reference to a new blog post that appeared today (Sept 29, 2011): [Data backup strategies for Windows and SQL Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidmcg/archive/2011/09/29/data-backup-strategies-for-windows-and-sql-azure.aspx)

Comment: Humm…guess I still need to read/learn more about SQL Azure because I didn’t know there was additional fees (although a small fee) for backing up your stuff…
Perhaps will continue with our current physical server and move to SQL Azure once these features become fully available. Thanks Joe!

Comment: @Vlince: I edited my answer to include a new blog entry that just appeared today.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the options that Joe has mentioned you can also use DAC as mentioned [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Backup-SQL-Azure-To-3b566585).  It is a little out of date as you can now import/export BACPAC files from blob storage in the portal.

Comment: Do you use DAC to manage your SQL Azure schema changes?  If so, how do you like it?

Comment: No, we don't use DAC for schema changes.  I just wanted people to be aware it was there for imports and exports.  It's strange it wasn't mentioned in either of the links in Joe's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Redgate offers a free tool to backup and restore a database from SQL Azure to SQL Server or Azure Blob Storage:

- [SQL Azure Backup](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-azure-backup/)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post on backing up your SQL Azure DB to a blog file using nothing more complex than some free command line tools and the windows task scheduler, should save you some money and hassle :-)

https://iainhunter.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/sql-azure-disaster-recovery/

Answer (score 0):

There is one project on [codeplex](http://azureautobackup.codeplex.com/) that is making possible to have a worker role to be acting as a backup agent.